# Why is commenting restricted to 50 rep?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, reputation

Why is it allowed to answer a questions, but for comments 50 reputation is needed. Isn't an answer much higher weighted than a comment, where you can point out something to the questioner without having to give an answer directly. Sometimes more information is needed to answer the question and user with less than 50 rep aren't able to ask for that.